# How to enable or disable input fields dynamically in angular js material design

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, angularjs-ng-disabled

I am having an issue with ng-disable. as i am using angular material i think this is not working. I want my input box to be disabled or enabled dynamically based on condition.

Note:- I have multiple input fields i want disable or enable all of the at a single shot.

I am trying like this

```
<md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
    <label for="Autocomplete">From</label>
    <input required type="text" class = "hideShadow" ng-model="FromLocation"
           uib-typeahead="state for state in states | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" 
          class="form-control" ng-disabled="isDisabled">
    <div ng-messages="searchFlight.FromLocation.$error">
    <div ng-message="required">Please enter from location</div>
     </div>
</md-input-container>
```

I am trying to access `ng-disabled="isDisabled"` dynamically like this

```
$scope.isDisabled = true;
```

But this is not working. May i know where i am going wrong?

Comment: Is angular working, no errors in console?

Comment: no errors in console

Comment: Mind sharing your js code?

Comment: i don't mind to share but it is quite heavy.

Comment: I got a solution. i am keeping my JS in wrong place my bad :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe the problem is in the way you did bind the property isDisabled.

try this:

```
$scope.model = {
    isDisabled: true
};
```

Then:

```
ng-disabled="model.isDisabled"
```

This problem occur when we try to bind a primitive property on a directive. We need to bind a attribute of a object to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable or disable the field by using ng-disabled

For example, if you want to disable a button initially and after performing something you want to enable the button,

```
<button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" ng-disabled="isDisabled" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>

$scope.isDisabled = true;

$scope.save = function(){
//after completing the operation set the values of variable to false
$scope.isDisabled = false;
}
```